# Flutter function timeout

Tags: flutter, flutter-timer

I am using flutter. I wrote a function, if it takes longer than 5 seconds, I want to redirect it to the page with a warning message.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your future function :

```
Future<void> func() async {}
```

Add timeout listener :

```
func().timeout(const Duration (seconds:5),onTimeout : () {
  // move to the page with warning message
});
```